# Request Function Returns Null in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a several form elements that I am dynamically creating with javascript when a user changes a number value in a textbox, by filling the innerHTML of a div like so:

```
dfinnerhtml = dfinnerhtml +  "<div class='field'> ";
dfinnerhtml = dfinnerhtml +  "<textarea name='textbox1" + suffix + "' type='text' id='textbox1" + suffix + "' value='' rows='4' cols='20' class='field'></textarea> ";
dfinnerhtml = dfinnerhtml +  "</div> ";
```

Then, in the aspx.vb code behind, when the user clicks the Save button, I run through a series of Requests to try and add the values that are in these form elements to a SQL string:

```
Dim DFTestValue1 As String
DFTestValue1 = Request("textbox" & c.ToString)
```

where c is a loop counter to the # of textboxes created (the input value mentioned above that triggers the create)

The problem here is that this code works in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox or Chrome. The Request() value returns null and nothing is saved. I hope I've explained this well enough.

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger, and stopped at the Request line to see what is available?  Request is much more than just a function...

Comment: The structure of the project prevents me from using the actual debugger, but I have tried to use FindControl to access the same object and it fails to find a control or a control parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is interested to know, the problem was that a stray  tag closed a div that preceded the  tag. Internet Explorer didn't seem to care and counted items beyond this point as part of the form.

Answer (score 1):

This post has probably got the answer:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1235816.aspx

Try the PreviousPage property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        TextBox pTextBox = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
        Response.Write("Previous Page TextBox: " + pTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```